# Individual and summarized tracking of group of websites

Tags: google-analytics

Let's say I own and control several fruit related sites with domains and subdomains and I want to track them individually as well as collectively to get total vistor values. What would be the right way to construct the analytics script settings with new asynchronous method?

let's say I have these domains:

```
apple.com
one.pear.com
one.peach.com
cherry.com
other.cherry.com
www.watermelon.com
```

I'm wondering if I'm doing it right and what to put in domain portion for first push:

What I have currently:

XXXXX - code for total tracking
YYYYY - code for individual tracking

```
<script>
  _gaq.push(
    ['_setAccount', 'XXXXX'],
    ['_setDomainName', 'whatdoiputhere?'],
    ['_trackPageview']);

  _gaq.push(
    ['b._setAccount', 'YYYYY'],
    ['b._setDomainName', '[current_domain(just domain)]'],
    ['b._trackPageview']
  );

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the exactly same _setDomainName for both trackers. And that must be the domain the code is currently in, you should use just the domain and not the subdomain. So for example for both cherry.com and other.cherry.com you should use the same tracking code:

```
<script>
  _gaq.push(
    ['_setAccount', 'XXXXX'],
    ['_setDomainName', 'cherry.com'],
    ['_trackPageview']);

  _gaq.push(
    ['b._setAccount', 'YYYYY'],
    ['b._setDomainName', 'cherry.com'],
    ['b._trackPageview']
  );

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Also if you want to do any other customization in one of the trackers then you MUST do exactly the same configuration in all trackers.

Each tracker will create a set of cookies and by using the same _setDomainName they will share the same set of cookies. This is better because you reduce the number of cookies but it's also tricky because both trackers must be compatible in order to share the same cookies, thus you should use the same configurations in both cookies.

If you do it differently you might end with a scenario where the trackers share a cookie but they don't agree on settings and might reset the cookies mutually resulting in completely broken trackers. Because it's so unstable Google say it's not a supported use case to have multiple trackers, but it's certainly possible if you follow the rules above.

If you use different configurations for _setDomainName than you might end up with cases where each tracker use a different set of cookies, which is good because they can't conflict anymore but in certain conditions they might be sharing the cookies, so it's not completely safe to assume 2 isolated sets.

Hope it helps

**UPDATE**

_setDomainName is used in analytics to figure out where it will save the cookies for Google Analytics. Thus it must match the current domain. If you are in domainX.com and try to set the domain to domainY.com than it won't be possible to store these cookies. In this case things can stop working, or maybe GA will just ignore your settings and go with default.

If you have different domains you need to pass cookies from one domain to the other in order to make GA understand it's the same visit. Google Analytics has some helpers to address this problem and it's well documented on the developer docs.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I'm trying to better understand the purpose of the _setDomainName. Does _setDomainName have to always match the current base domain of the site? or can I put whatever I want in it? If I track multiple different domains with same tracking code, do they all have to have the correct base domain set as _setDomainName or could I set it to something like companyname.com for all of them?